# Powershell if -or statements

Tags: powershell

I cannot understand why this simple powershell -OR isn't working.  If I use anything greater then 3 the if statement works, but the OR isn't working.  If I use zero which would be less then 1 it doesn't enter the if block.

```
if($ActionType -gt 3 -Or $ActionType -lt 1)
{
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you put in more parentheses?

Comment: Same outcome.  if({$ActionType -gt 3} -Or {$ActionType -lt 1})

Comment: Was worth a try.  :)

Comment: Any chance $ActionType.GetType().FullName returns System.String?

Comment: I have a feeling that `$ActionType` is a string.  Can you convert it to an integer?

Comment: Insufficient information in your question. Please post a short sample that contains only the absolute minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. (The code you have posted does not do that. What is `$ActionType`?)

Answer (score 2):

In-line with the commentators, it appears you're trying to compare a `string` to an `int`.

Assuming `$ActionType.Length != 0 || null`:

```
Try
{
    $Compare = [int]$ActionType
    if ($Compare -gt 3 -or $Compare -lt 1) { <# ... #> }
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "Conversion failed! $PSItem"
}
```

---

In this particular scenario, I think I'd prefer a cleaner syntax, though:

```
if (1,2,3 -notcontains $ActionType) { }
```

Comment: Ill give that a try.  I did specify actiontype as a int.